# How can I pass a var between routes funcs and change it in every controller?

Tags: go, go-gin

I want to pass var and change it globally in every controller between routes so if controller1 change var to "as" I want controller2 to use the new value of the var = "as". How can I do it?
something like this

main.go:

```
var test []string

func NewRouter() *gin.Engine {
    gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
    r := gin.New()
    r.GET("/ping", gets(test))
    r.Run(":6030")
    return r
}
```

controller.go:

```
func gets(test) gin.HandlerFunc {
   fn := func(c *gin.Context){
               // Here I want to change my var (test) and I want to change it globally so if any another function use it I want to use the new value I just change it here
         }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a pointer to the value you want to change, and you need to use a mutex to avoid data races.

Answer (score 1):

The comment of `mkopriva` already give you a solution on how to using `mutex`.

However, since golang promote `share memory by communicating`, I propose another solution using `channel`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
  r := NewRouter()
  r.Run(":6030")
}

var test = []string{"abc"}

func NewRouter() *gin.Engine {
    gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
    r := gin.New()

    updateChan := make(chan []string, 0)
    r.GET("/", gets(updateChan))
    r.GET("/mn", er(updateChan))
    return r
}

func gets(updateChan chan []string) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context){
        fmt.Println("before update in get, test=",test)
        newTest := []string{"def"}
        updateChan <- newTest
  }

}

func er(updateChan chan []string) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context){
        test = <-updateChan
        fmt.Println("get a new value for test in er, test=",test)

  }

}
```

With an unbuffered channel `updateChan`, test will always be update with the latest input pushed to `updateChan` channel. And no data race will happen here.

Of course this is just a simple demonstration and there are lot more stuff to make a complete HTTP server with gin. But I limit the scope of the demonstration to `channel` usage only.

Comment: hello @TranvuXuannhat it's works. but i've small problem when i try to loop the chan in another route , some thing like `r.GET("/mn", er(updateChan))` when i reach to **/mn** on browser it timeouts, i think coz i didn't close the chan this happen but how i should handle this?

Comment: If you loop the chan, it will wait for the new message from the updateChan to come and do something, then waiting again. If you only want to get the latest updated value, just get the first message, don't loop. I will update the answer

Comment: hello @TranvuXuannhat, this's not what i want, i wanna loop the chan and get all values into chan in another function, i'll use this chan in another function so how i can do it?